# Calculate sum and percentage from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php

I need to calculate the sum of missing hours at an internship and then display said sum in percentage. For example: in this case, the internship has 400 hours and somebody was missing 2 times for 5 hours (sum would be 10), so the percentage would display 2,5.

| Sum | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2,5% |

Right now, I only have how to calculate and display the sum, but don't know how to show the percentage of said sum. Here is the PHP code I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(`fehlzeit`) as 'summe' FROM fehlzeiten WHERE `praktikumsartkuerzel`= 'AP' ";

$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>". $row["summe"] ."</td></tr>";
         }
               echo "</table>";
         }
         else {
               echo "0 result";
         }
         $conn-> close();
```

This is the code I tried, but it didn't work:

```
   $sql = "SELECT SUM(`fehlzeit`) as 'summe' FROM fehlzeiten WHERE `praktikumsartkuerzel`= 'AP' ";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);
    $allowed = 400;
    
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>". $row["summe"] ."</td></tr>";
                 }
                       echo "</table>";
                 }
                 else {
                       echo "0 result";
                 }
    $procent = $result / $allowed;
    echo $procent;      
    $conn-> close();
```

For non-German speakers:
fehlzeit means absenteeism,
praktikumsartkuerzel means Type of internship abbreviation,
summe means sum.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: this  $procent = $result / $allowed; should be  $procent = $row["summe"] / $allowed;

Comment: `10/(400-10)` gives 0.0256, so what is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your percent to appear in your HTML table, you should replace this

```php
echo "<tr><td>". $row["summe"] ."</td></tr>";
```

with this

```php
echo "<tr><td>". $row["summe"] ."</td><td>". $row["summe"] / $allowed ."</td> </tr>";
```

putting two `<td> ... </td>` columns in the row.